# Importing data from MySQL to Postgres with kafka

Tags: mysql, postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have a sync process between MySQL and Postgres that is successful only with one table.
Once I create a new table and add few records from the MySQL side, I can't find the data in Postgres. Could you help me, please?

Comment: hi hassene Fliss, welcome to SO, can you had what you tried already and also the errors you're getting

Comment: Tidied up typing.

Comment: Hi dege , I tried this project in github.
https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/unwrap-smt    the issue is that no error is generated , with this packege , the table customer is synced when i add data to mysql , it s transferred to Postgres with no issue , but when i create a new table in mysql , and add data , no data is generated , neither the table is created in postgres . i dont know if i miss something

Answer (score 0):

So I know this is really late, but I believe the answer lies in the sink json.

```
    "name": "jdbc-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "customers",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/inventory?user=postgresuser&password=postgrespw",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "delete.enabled": "true",
        "pk.fields": "id",
        "pk.mode": "record_key"
    }
}
```

So the topic under focus here is customers which is the table in the mysql database. I would add whatever the name of your table is here after customers for it to pick up.